# Is there a kotlin idiomatic way of checking that a sequence is at least N elements?

Tags: kotlin

Looking for a Kotlin idiomatic way of establishing a sequence has a minimum number of elements. I've accomplished it with this so far:

```
fun <T> Sequence<T>.hasMinimum(threshold: Int): Boolean =
    take(threshold).toList().size == threshold
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: `count >= threshold`

Comment: If the sequence has 10,000 elements but my threshold is 5 I want the sequence to terminate after reaching 5.

Comment: Ah, good point. Then the best I’ve got is replacing your `toList().size` with `count`.

Comment: True that does help cut down more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fun <T> Sequence<T>.hasMinimum(threshold: Int) = take(threshold).count() == threshold
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use `count()` because it is a terminal operator

> Returns the number of elements in this sequence.
>
> operation is *terminal*.

`public fun <T> Sequence<T>.count(): Int {...}`

for your case we can write it.

```
fun <T> Sequence<T>.hasMinimum(threshold: Int): Boolean =
            count() == threshold
```

Comment: This is a terminal operator but will continue processing the sequence until it is done. I wan't to terminate once my threshold has been reached. Also in your function you are looking for == threshold, I think it should be >= threshold.

Comment: @Mojtaba Haddadi This doesn't work, you need to use `take()` as suggested in other answers. Even if you change `count() >= threshold`, then `sequenceOf(1, 2).hasMinimum(3)` returns `true`

Comment: @Rjbcc58, So edit you question and add this functionality to it.

Comment: The question is asking for "minimum" number of elements already.